# Development DropDowns List error on empty value

Tags: vba, excel

I have a simple dropdown list named `DD8`. It uses 50 rows as control, the problem is that for now only 45 rows are used. That means that in the dropdown list there are 5 empty rows. The problem is that if someone select one empty row, or don't select anything (default is empty) the fallowing code will show error :

```
With Worksheets(1)
        NameProf = .DropDowns("DD8").List _
            (.DropDowns("DD8").ListIndex)
   End With
```

I tried things like `if .DropDowns("DD8").List (.DropDowns("DD8").ListIndex) != ""` but ofc, it shows error. I searched how to select only used rows with the DropDown list of the development tab but it doesn't seem to be possible.

I have to select 50 rows because new customers can be added.

Do you know how it can be achieved ?

Answer (score 0):

If new customers can be added, then I imagine, and hope for you, that it goes above 50.... so it's not just an issue of having 5 blanks for now to not be an option, but also allowing customers 50-2,483 also be on there when they come along. ---- Without more details on your code, I believe this suggestion should help 'guide' you but not immediately solve your issue.

Essentially, whenever you call to have your dropdown populated, you want some code to find the last row of data in the customers column, and then assign your dropdown to populate with the starting row of your customers to the lastrow. This way no matter how many customers you have 2, 48, 189... they will show in your dropdown without that issue occurring. A simple google search will yield how to find the last row in excel.

Sorry I couldn't just bust out the code to make it work for you right this second, but I think this should be a good starting point for you.

Comment: Don't worry about the number of customers, this was some kind of example. My list control is simply `Customers!$B$4:$B$54`. I tried to dynamicaly add items on open worksheet but I can't figure out how. I know how to do all of this with a dropdown list created with the data tab. My problem is that I have to use the development tool to create the dropdown list and it doesn't seem to work the same way